# How to delete the default Help button in CPropertySheet in MFC?

Tags: mfc, button, cpropertysheet

I am using `CPropertySheet` class for my design in MFC application, normally in `CPropertySheet` there would be 4 default buttons. I want to hide/delete the HELP button. I tried the following, but it's not working/neither responding. I had this written in my `CPropertyPage` class
is there any other way...

> ```
> m_psh.dwFlags &= ~PSH_HASHELP;
> ```

Comment: Can you show us the code leading up to CPropertySheet::AddPage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Destroy the Help button
CButton *btnHelp;

btnHelp = reinterpret_cast<CButton *>(GetDlgItem(IDHELP));
btnHelp->DestroyWindow();
```

Comment: tanx 4 ur reply...its not a normal button that u can delete using the above coding...I am using CPropertySheet -its an object which holds your Property Page...it will not work..some other way

Comment: I know you are using the CPropertySheet, and a button is a button. You Can try ((CWnd*)GetDlgItem(IDHELP))->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE); or can looks at the various samples on internet: http://www.functionx.com/visualc/articles/propsheetbtn.htm

Comment: Hi Priyank, your solution is giving 'Debug Assertion Failed' in debug and 'Access Violation' error in release mode. I saw everywhere it is working for others but me .. why? What could be the difference?

Answer (score 14):

The property pages also have a `HASHELP` flag that needs to be cleared. The following code in the constructor of the property sheet should work:

```
// After the last AddPage() call:
m_psh.dwFlags &= ~PSH_HASHELP;
for(int i=0; i<GetPageCount(); ++i)
    GetPage(i)->m_psp.dwFlags &= ~PSP_HASHELP;
```

Alternatively, one can also modify the `m_psp` flag for each individual page before calling `AddPage()`:

```
m_psh.dwFlags &= ~PSH_HASHELP;
page1.m_psp.dwFlags &= ~PSP_HASHELP;
AddPage(&page1);
// ...
```

Comment: Notice the difference between `PS`**H`**`_HASHELP` and `PS`**P**`_HASHELP`.
I was trying this with a `CMFCPropertySheet`, this code only turned the Help button disabled because I mistyped. But it is now hiding the button as it is supposed.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: If you want to remove the Apply button, just add `m_psh.dwFlags |= PSH_NOAPPLYNOW;` . The pages do not have this flag, so there is nothing to do on them.

Answer (score 4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/37k4h0bh(v=vs.80).aspx

You have to remove the flag from the sheet and all pages...

```
mySheet.m_psh.dwFlags &= ~PSH_HASHELP;
page1.m_psp.dwFlags &= ~PSP_HASHELP;
page2.m_psp.dwFlags &= ~PSP_HASHELP;
```

...

Take care of the difference: m_ps**h** vs. m_ps**p** and PS**H**_HASHELP vs. PS**P**_HASHELP

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project's main cpp file (where theApp is defined).
Remove this line: `ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, CWinApp::OnHelp)`

Aditya Palanki

Comment: This does not hide nor deletes the Help button. Only disconnects the button from its handler function. And worse ... it removes the handler in other places were you need it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work out :

Override the OnNotify method of the class derived from PropertySheet ,write the following code into it

CWnd *hwnd = GetDlgItem(IDHELP); 
hwnd->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

Comment: This is unnecessary complication.